# Convert QString/QByteArray to Scientific Notation qt

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion

Is there a way to easily convert a `QByteArray` or `QString` or `int` displaying some large integer to scientific notation? I need to display it as a string in a `QLineEdit`.

I'm sure this has already been asked, but I haven't found what I'm looking for.

Convert `QByteArray`: `475000000` to `QString`: `4.75E8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QString aaa("475000000");
ui->lineEdit->setText(QString::number(aaa.toDouble()));
```

Output:

```
4.75e+08
```

Or

```
QString aaa("475000000");
QString formatted = QString::number(aaa.toDouble()).remove("+");
ui->lineEdit->setText(formatted.toUpper());
```

Output:

```
4.75E08

QString aaa("475000000");
QString formatted = QString::number(aaa.toDouble()).remove("+");
formatted.replace("e0","E");
ui->lineEdit->setText(formatted.toUpper());
```

Output:

```
4.75E8
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest choice is to convert string to number and then number to string.
There are many possibilities:

```
QString aaa("475000000");
double value = aaa.toDouble();
QString cStyleResult = QString::number(value, 'e');
QString localeAwareResult = QLocale::system().toString(value, 'e');
QString noLocaleFormat = QString("value=%1").arg(value, 0, 'e');
QString localeAwareFormat = QString("value=%L1").arg(value, 0, 'e');
```